# Send LocalNotification when enter on the view

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a problem that I can't send a notification when I open a page/view. In IonicView.enter i had put an alert and worked well, but when I call the function, didn't worked. It just work manually. I don't know how to handle this, if can anyone help me, I appreciate that.

```js
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {
 
  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaLocalNotification:schedule',
   function (event, notification, state) {
    console.log("SCHEDULE");
    console.log('event', event);
    console.log('notification', notification);
    console.log('state', state);
   });
 $rootScope.$on('$cordovaLocalNotification:trigger',
   function (event, notification, state) {
    console.log("TRIGGER");
    console.log('event', event);
    console.log('notification', notification);
    console.log('state', state);
   });

  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaLocalNotification:update',
   function (event, notification, state) {
    console.log('UPDATE');
    console.log('event', event);
    console.log('notification', notification);
    console.log('state', state);
   });

  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaLocalNotification:cancel',
   function (event, notification, state) {
    console.log('CANCEL');
    console.log('event', event);
    console.log('notification', notification);
    console.log('state', state);
   });
   
  
  // Form data for the login modal
  $scope.loginData = {};

  // Create the login modal that we will use later
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templatesInfo/login.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });

  // Triggered in the login modal to close it
  $scope.closeLogin = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };
  
  $scope.load = function(fct){
 window.onload(fct, '_system');
};


    $scope.goBack = function () {
     window.history.back();
};



  // Open the login modal
  $scope.login = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };

  // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
  $scope.doLogin = function() {
    console.log('Doing login', $scope.loginData);

    // Simulate a login delay. Remove this and replace with your login
    // code if using a login system
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.closeLogin();
    }, 1000);
  };
})

.controller('SampleController',
    function ($scope, $cordovaLocalNotification, $ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
            $scope.scheduleInstantNotification = function () {
                $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
                    id: 1,
                    text: 'Instant Notification',
                    title: 'Instant'
                }).then(function () {
                    alert("Instant Notification set");
                });;
            };
   
   $scope.$on("$ionicView.enter", function(){
                 // handle event
                 $scope.scheduleInstantNotification();
            });
  });
    })

.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.playlists = [
    { title: 'Reggae', id: 1 },
    { title: 'Chill', id: 2 },
    { title: 'Dubstep', id: 3 },
    { title: 'Indie', id: 4 },
    { title: 'Rap', id: 5 },
    { title: 'Cowbell', id: 6 }
  ];
})

.controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 768px)" href="portrait.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="landscape.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

 <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
  <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
 

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/appInfo.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllersInfo.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/evothings/evothings.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

 
 
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="SampleController">
  
 <ion-nav-view>
 
 
  
 </ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

```html
<ion-view view-title="Information">
  <ion-content>
  

  <div class="list card" >

    <div class="item item-avatar" >
   
   <h2>Dr. Therese Ouellet</h2>
   <p>Agriculture and Angri food Canada</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item item-body">
   <img class="full-image" src="img/therese.jpg">
   <p>
     This is a "Facebook" styled Card. The header is created from a Thumbnail List item,
     the content is from a card-body consisting of an image and paragraph text. The footer
     consists of tabs, icons aligned left, within the card-footer.
   </p>
   
    </div>


 </div>

  <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="scheduleInstantNotification()">
          Instant 
     </button>
 
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```